# Audio sound is not working in video of Pygame.It is just like a muted video

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio, pygame

Here is my code. When I run it in Python 2.7 in Tkinter graphical mode with help of abutton it shows pygame movie screen but without sound.....

I also tried it separately but there is no sound there......

```
import pygame

FPS = 60

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
movie = pygame.movie.Movie('1.MPG')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(movie.get_size())
movie_screen = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size()).convert()

movie.set_display(movie_screen)
movie.play()


playing = True
while playing:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            movie.stop()
            playing = False

    screen.blit(movie_screen,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

check it please someone....

Answer (score 1):

Try `pygame.movie.set_volume(1)`
[wiki](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/movie.html#pygame.movie.Movie.set_volume%22)

and check the basics: are your speakers on?
does the movie have sound at all?

Answer (score 1):

According this [link](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=26374&p=240368): try to add

```
pygame.mixer.quit()
```

before

```
movie = pygame.movie.Movie('1.MPG')
```